# What plastic material blocks the most amount of light?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, plastic, lighting

If I have a grid array of LED's surrounded by roughly 0.7mm thickness plastic walls. What material at this thickness would prevent light bleed side to side so that individual LED's can light up but not light up their neighbor? [image: grid]

Comment: Polypropylene is versatile and cheap.  But, this is actually a pretty open ended question.  Lots of materials will do the job. Tell us more about what your goal is (avoid the x-y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MohammadAthar my goal is to simply block light between LED's. The 0.7mm is a pre-defined constraint that I'm dealing with. Thanks for suggesting Polypropylene. A manufacturer I've spoken with has suggested PC-ABS. I'm merely seeing if another engineer has had to previously deal with this same thickness constraint before.

Comment: @Rogue-OP May i know, the frequency of lights ? And should the plastic be totally transparent ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Full spectrum (RGB LED's) and the plastic should be opaque (not transparent)

Answer (score 1):

A foil coated plastic would be ideal as a metallic surface prevents light bleed and is easily manufactured. The higher the density of any material the less transparent they tend to be except in the case of transparent ones, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You want a polymer that is strong and easy to injection mold in thin sections (.7mm). Black nylon would be perfect.